Подскажите правильное ли решение задачи про мышь
Ограничение времени - 1 секунда
Ограничение памяти - 256Mb
Мышь очень любит есть конфеты, но её поместили в таблицу размера n * m. Каждая клетка этой таблицы огорожена стенками и содержит в себе одну очень вкусную конфету. Мышь может прогрызть любую стенку, но она хочет сделать это минимально возможное число раз. Вычислите, какое минимальное число стенок ей нужно будет прогрызть, чтобы съесть все конфеты.
Формат входных данных
В единственной строке входного файла содержится два числа n и m (1 <= n, m <= 10^9).
Формат выходных данных
Выведите единственное число -- ответ на задачу.
Примеры данных
Пример 1:
Ввод:
2 2

Вывод:
3

Пример 2:
Ввод:
1 6

Вывод:
5

Я решила так:
n, m = map(int, input().split())
print(n * m - 1)


А что вам ответила проверяющая система? :)

@Harry увы, но её нет) Только условие задачи и пара тестов) Надеялась услышать, что логика верна)

мышь грызла по спирали и умерла от диабета

@Zhihar Грустно( А ещё наверное потому что объелась несъедобных стен(

Да вроде бы... Чтобы попасть в очередную ячейку, нужно прогрызть стенку.

@Harry спасибо большое :)
